# I am using routing in MVC. But when i am using other url same as route url it is redirecting to the same action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "GetProductBySubcategory",      // Route name
     "{category}/{SubCategoryName}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Product", action = "GetProductBySubCategoryName" 
});
```

Here is my route that is working fine.
But when is am using the url Like `localhost:12345/Admin/Login` then it use the route url and redirect to `GetProductBySubCategoryName` action.
actually i am using @Url.RouteUrl() method to call the route. which is working good. But when other url like Account/Register means which have only two keys redirect to action given in the route.
I am using other routes

All routes that i am using is as follow:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "GetProductByCategory",                                          
        "{category}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "GetProductByCategoryName" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
       "GetProductBySubcategory",
       "{category}/{SubCategoryName}",
       new { controller = "Product", action = "GetProductBySubCategoryName" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ProductByNameRoute",
        "{category}/{subcategory}/{style}/{productName}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetails" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

this is my route.config file.
i am not able to call sign in link, login link the all goes to route url.

acctually i want to route url like if i click on getproductbycategory url will domain/category and if i click on getproductbysubcategory url will be domain/category/subcategory.
Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: which is exactly what this route says - note that you have no `{action}`nor `{controller}` in your socalled `URL with parameters`

Comment: this is not gonna be easy as this one will catch-all - without seeing the rest it's hard to give advice

Comment: Your first route matches anything with one segment. Your second one matches anything with 2 segments. You need to make your routes specific so they can be matched, e.g. `routes.MapRoute("GetProductByCategory", "Product/{category}", new { controller = "Product", action = "GetProductByCategoryName" });` so they can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on MVC 5 you can easily achieve this by attribute routing, without modifying the route table.

[Attribute Routing in MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)